# Node Red function node change or alter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, node-red

I have been trying to use a function block for my multiple sensor project Node Red display, and everywhere i try to learn about the function node i see it just has a function tab. Mine looks different i have this "On Start" "On Message" and "On Stop" which i dont want ori cant find on how to use this online. [This is what mine looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RV82h.png)

anyone know how i can change this or work with ths?

Answer (score 1):

The original function node had the one tab where you enter the code that should be run whenever a message arrives at the node.

In more recent releases, there are tabs that let you provide code that is run when the node is first deployed and when it is stopped.

The 'on message' tab is the equivalent of the older version's single tab.